# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error Web service

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services

I am trying to send a SOAP XML to oracle webservice. Service reference does not work well so I decide to use webrequest but I am getting an errror "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. "

```
   string envelope = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.xml");
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(envelope);

    byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxxxx" + ":" + "xxxxx");
    string credentials = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);

    HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ehpq-test.fa.em2.oraclecloud.com/fscmService/SupplierServiceV2");

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://ehpq-test.fa.em2.oraclecloud.com/fscmService/SupplierServiceV2");

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just my opinion but if the *"service reference does not work well"* trying an even more brittle solution is not the way I'd choose. With the service reference you could at least have the chance to get a more specific service fault than a http 500.

Comment: @Filburt because using service reference all value are being send even if i did not set a value that cause the error. The client also experience this before and they suggest using webrequest instead. 
Here is the reference for webrequest https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/sales/r13-update17d/oesws/-NET-Framework.html

Comment: How would it make any difference if you do not set a value on a proxy class or in a hand built xml soap message? If the service method requires a value if will fail whichever way you build the request.

Comment: @Filburt that is what I actually told to them. But they insist of using soap xml

Comment: It will always be soap xml in the end. Using the web service client just spares you building the message yourself. Your only problem is passing the required parameters for the service method you want to call. The service will always reject any call whichever way it is built if it is missing required input values.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the working request with the non working request. The error 500 indicates you are not completing the connection.  Compare the header and see what is missing from the non working request and add missing items.  The soap is working so you should be able to add what is missing and make it look like the working SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

It can be very difficult to diagnose the problem that has occurred in the server from your client code. If you have access to the server, you can view the error logs for the web server.

For instance, with Nginx on Ubuntu you would want to navigate to `/var/log/nginx` directory and then either use `nano` or `tail -f` to view the full contents of the file `error.log` or similarly named. This would be the place that lists the exact cause of the server to throw a 500. It may not be the case that your request is malformed, but that the endpoint is misconfigured server-side.

Comment: I don't have access to their server. It is oracle web service by the way